# React Router not showing default homepage on pageload

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am just learning to use React Router and I've got my main App.js file looking like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route  path="/resources" exact component={Resources} />
          <Route  path="/info" exact component={Info} />
          <Route  path="/" exact component={Home} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue that I am having is that when the page initially loads (after "npm start" or upon visiting where it's deployed on github-pages) the Home component isn't displayed. However, when I navigate to a different route (via the Links in the Navbar component) the different route works as usual. I can then return to the Home component via the same Navbar and this time it *does* display. Then, when I refresh the page on the Home page it loads correctly. If I kill the development server and restart it, the homepage no longer loads. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: <Route  path="/" exact component={Home} /> move it at the top in route list

Comment: that didn't work, it's only on the bottom because I was experimenting with that, but thanks

Comment: instead of having components try it like this: eg:
<Route  path="/resources" exact />
<Home />
</Route>
Similarily for others

Comment: @Sakshi I've just tried that, as well as tried the routes in reverse order... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/resources" component={resources} />
        <Route path="/info" component={Info} />
        <Route path="*">
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Would you mind explaining why this worked?

Comment: It allows to make a redirect if the url does not exist or if it is false

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after "npm start" or upon visiting where it's deployed on github-pages it is not going to home.
I'm using "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",

this is my code

export default function App() {
return (

```
  <Routes>
  <div className="nav-fixed">
    <Navbar />
  </div>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
    <Route path="/services" element={<Services />} />
    <Route path="/about_us" element={<About_us />} />
    <Footer />
  </Routes>
  
</div>
```

);
}